# Regx only number after Searchword

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use Regex in VBA for analyzing a txt file.

The result should only show the first number after the searchword. In my syntax not all possibilities are in the result. and it also shows numbers in the next line. 
Thx 4 Help

This is my regex
(Sword)?\d

https://regex101.com/r/fLx1qN/1

In my syntax not all possibilities are in the result. and it also shows numbers in the next line

Comment: `The result should only show the first number after the searchword` in each line or in complete string you have ? also should the number appear immediately  after the searchword or there can be any other characters in between

Comment: In each line.  like in the example there could be whitespaces or sometimes a :

Comment: is the searcword need to case insensitive ? is the searchword always at start of string ? can there  be multiple occurrences of searchword in same line ?

Comment: is this is what you're after [`(Sword)[^\d]*\d`](https://regex101.com/r/fLx1qN/3)

Comment: If you only want to keep the digits, try `\bSword\b\D+(\d+)` https://regex101.com/r/COIBkz/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't very precise about which strings should match and which ones shouldn't.

- **Number** is ambiguous. Do you mean digit, or integer?
- **After** is ambiguous. Do you mean immediately after, any time after?
- Do you want to match the *number* immediately after the search word? Or can it follow anywhere after the search word?
- Is the search meant to be case sensitive?

For digit use: `(Sword)[^\d]*(\d)`, for integer use: `(Sword)[^\d]*(-?\d+)`

For immediately after (allowing for space and colon) use: `(Sword)[:\s]*(\d)`

To make the expression case insensitive with VBA, use the following reference: https://www.regular-expressions.info/vbscript.html

```
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Pattern = "(Sword)[^\d]*(-?\d+)"
myRegExp.IgnoreCase = True
```

Comment: (Sword)[^\d]*(-?\d+) iss nearly what i am searching for with one difference the searchword should  be not case sensitiv

Comment: Updated to the answer to include case insensitive expression.

Comment: Works great! Thx a lot. Could you explain for what - before the questionmark is needed? Is there a possibility to ignore numbers which have more than 2 digits? I tried {1,2} but this will give back only first 2 digits of the number found but i want to ignore theses numbers

Comment: `-?` means 1 or 0 `-` characters. Again, the term *number* is ambiguous, this allows for negative integers. You can omit `-?` altogether if you don't care about negative values. If you want to match on between 1 and 2 digits, you can use a lookahead expression. Specifically: `(Sword)[^\d]*(-?\d{1,2}(?!\d))`. `(?!\d)` is a negative lookahead expression. See also: https://www.regular-expressions.info/refadv.html

Comment: If you found this answer helpful please accept and upvote it.

Comment: I did a lot of testing and now I am facing a new problem. sometimes a date is behind the sword. this shall not match I tried to add \s the end. (Sword)[^\d]*(-?\d{1,2}(?!\d))\s. This solves the problem but I discovered a new problem if in the txt are no 2 digits after sword he matches 2 digits after linebreak. Any ideas to avoid that? https://regex101.com/r/ADXYII/3/ (Problem is last sword in example)

Comment: Can you include clear examples in regex101 on what should and shouldn't match? That would make it easier to understand your specific expectations.

Comment: I try to extract version numbers from diffrent types of data formats (Excel, txt etc) the version has not much more than 2 digits and has to in line not below. https://regex101.com/r/ADXYII/5/   https://ibb.co/DtH7wWP

Comment: I think   (Version)[^\d|^\n]*(-?\d{1,2}(?!\d))(\s) will solve the problem. Will test it more deeply. thx 4 your help